# ¿Es normal tener acceso a ciertas zonas limitadas por reputación?

Tags: soporte

El otro día a raíz de una serie de preguntas y revisiones por parte de usuarios con ciertos privilegios por la reputación obtenida, me fijé que aparece junto a algunos comentarios un enlace denomidado `From Review`.

> *He buscado en SOes, pero no he encontrado las que ví el otro día, así que he tomado capturas y enlaces de SO*

[image: From Review Link]
*Se puede encontrar en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940395/6272471) en el cuarto (4º) comentario.*

Esta zona normalmente, debido a la reputación suele tener este aspecto con el correspondiente aviso de que se necesita X reputación para realizar revisiones.

[image: Aviso limitación]

Pero en el caso de acceder a través del enlace del comentario, permite ver el `post`en revisión y las acciones de los revisores.

[image: Panel de revisión]

A ver, no te permite realizar ninguna acción de revisión.

Para los que tenéis estos privilegios os resultará normal verlos, pero para los que aún no los tenemos, en mi caso particular me resulta extraño tener acceso a esa zona.

¿No debería ser visible, tanto el enlace de los comentarios como las acciones de los revisores solo a estos?

> *En caso de ser un comportamiento controlado y autorizado, pues aprovecho entonces para hacer un reporte de traducción de "From Review".*

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido es un comportamiento normal :). Simplemente cuándo ves esos comentarios te permite ver esa revisión específica para no ocultar información al usuario (aquí en SOes también es así).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es normal, y es una característica diseñada de esa forma.

Análogamente, podrás ver las revisiones de cualquier usuario yendo a
Usuarios -> Actividad -> Todas Las Acciones -> Revisiones

Esta información está disponible para cualquier usuario. Por ejemplo, estas son mis revisiones: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano?tab=activity&sort=reviews

El único caso en el que no podrás ver una revisión directamente es cuando la revisión aún está activa, y tenés reputación para revisarla. En ese caso, deberás realizar la revisión primero.

Comment: Todo aclarado entonces. No conocía el acceso a revisiones desde cada usuario.